# django startproject creating old project layout

Tags: django

I recently started looking into django and I started with the tutorial.

I noticed that `django-admin.py startproject project_name` creates a flat file system structure.

According to the tutorial, the project layout has changed:

> The default project layout recently changed. If you're seeing a "flat" layout (with no inner mysite/ directory), you're probably using a version of Django that doesn't match this tutorial version. You'll want to either switch to the older tutorial or the newer Django version.

I checked the version of django by running:

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

And I have the latest version 1.3.1

I was wondering if it is possible that I have two copies of django installed?? Or how can I solve this? I want to make sure that I have the latest django running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the confusion.

All 1.3 versions use the old flat layout. The development version - recently tagged as 1.4 alpha - uses the new one. You should be using the [documentation that matches your version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: gotcha! I thought that by "latest" version they meant latest official version. Thanks